# How many instances of Kere and Ketiv?

Tags: tanach, mesorah-tradition

How many instances of Kere and Ketiv appear within the TaNaKh?

And are there any sources that list every verse in which they occur?

And what are the underlying reasons for differences in count?

---

For example, [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/527368?seq=9#metadata_info_tab_contents) states there are 1359 instances, but it also states:

> But the number is larger...

Comment: Why is it relevant for you? Could you please add some background?

Comment: There are debates about what words are kri/ktiv and debates about which ambiguous spellings count as kri/ktiv

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5272/15256 ?

Comment: For instance, is נַעֲרָ a kri/ktiv? It's perfectly intelligible as is, even if it's not the standard spelling.

Comment: Is anyone counting Hashem's name here? *Lots* of appearances.

Answer (score 1):

How many instances of Qere and Ketiv appear within the TaNaKh? = **1,274** Total - Based on [https://www.tanakhml.org/d71.php2xml?sfr=1&prq=8]

Comment: The number "1274" is according to whom? As DoubleAA pointed out above, there are debates as to what constitutes kere/ketiv

Comment: The source cited documents 1,274 total instances of Qere/Ketiv notations. The site has listed each individual notation throughout the Tanakh. - As a reference tool, I hope the website helps in your studies : [https://www.tanakhml.org/d71.php2xml?sfr=1&prq=8]